# Is it possible to make batch requests on the github api?

Tags: node.js, request, batch-processing, github-api

I want to be able to get an array of users for a series of repositories. As far as I know, the only way to achieve that is to loop through the repositories and make a request for each. Unfortunately, this eats up my api-hit-count, which is limited to 5000/hour. Is there a way that I can pass up an array of repositories, and get an 2d array of JSON?

Note: I'm writing this using node.js

Current situation

```
for( var iRepo=0; iRepo<repos.length; ++iRepo )
    request(repo.stargazers_url, parseUserCallback )
```

I want to do

```
request( batchEndpoint, {repos:repos}, parseRepoUserMapCallback )
```

This seems like something that could be solved with a simple google search, but searching for anything with "GitHub" in it just brings up various repositories.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sadly, GitHub's API documentation has no signs of any form of batch operations for this endpoint.

So you might want to do caching or figure out something else.

Comment: That's correct -- the GitHub API doesn't support batch operations currently.

Answer (score 2):

The better way to perform such an operation would be to use the [GitHub GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql). GraphQL allows you to get exactly and only what you need from the API.

I suggest you consider abandoning the REST api and switching to the GraphQL one.

Comment: Good idea but it's worth noting the GraphQL API and REST API support different features. E.g. there doesn't appear to be a GraphQL connection between repos and GH Actions workflows so I couldn't batch requests for repo workflows. Had to stick with the REST API instead.